# Instantiate collection of object from class constructor

Tags: c#, collections

I am trying to instantiate a collection of object from a class constructor however I am having this error "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

```
 namespace MVVM
{
    public class MoviesPageViewModel
    {
        public class MoviesPageViewModel
        {
            public List<MovieCategory> Items { get; set; }

            public MoviesPageViewModel()
            {
                var movies = new List<Movie>
                             {
                                 new Movie {Title = "The Ewok Adventure", Category = "Adventure", Subtitle = "The Towani family civilian shuttlecraft crashes on the forest moon of Endor.", Image = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/y6HdTlqgcZ6EdsKR1uP03WgBe0C.jpg"},
                                 new Movie {Title = "The In-Laws", Category = "Adventure", Subtitle = "In preparation for his daughter's wedding, dentist Sheldon ", Image = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/9FlFW9zhuoOpS8frAFR9cCnJ6Sg.jpg"},
                                 new Movie {Title = "The Man Called Flintstone", Category = "Adventure", Subtitle = "In this feature-length film based on the Flintstones TV show", Image = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/6qyVUkbDBuBOUVVplIDGaQf6jZL.jpg"},

                                 new Movie {Title = "Super Fuzz", Category = "Comedy", Subtitle = "Dave Speed is no ordinary Miami cop--he is an irradiated Miami cop ", Image = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/bueVXkpCDPX0TlsWd3Uk7QKO3kD.jpg"},
                                 new Movie {Title = "The Knock Out Cop", Category = "Comedy", Subtitle = "This cop doesn't carry a gun - his fist is loaded!", Image = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/mzlw8rHGUSDobS1MJgz8jXXPM06.jpg"},
                                 new Movie {Title = "Best Worst Movie", Category = "Comedy", Subtitle = "A look at the making of the film Troll 2 (1990) ", Image = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/5LjbAjkPBUOD9N2QFPSuTyhomx4.jpg"},

                                 new Movie {Title = "The Last Unicorn", Category = "Fantasy", Subtitle = "A brave unicorn and a magician fight an evil king", Image = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/iO6P5vV1TMwSuisZDtNBDNpOxwR.jpg"},
                                 new Movie {Title = "Blithe Spirit", Category = "Fantasy", Subtitle = "An English mystery novelist invites a medium", Image = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/gwu4c10lpgHUrMqr9CBNq2FYTpN.jpg"},
                                 new Movie {Title = "Here Comes Mr. Jordan", Category = "Fantasy", Subtitle = "Boxer Joe Pendleton, flying to his next fight", Image = "http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/9cnWl7inQVX6wznjYNmQmJXVD6J.jpg"},
                             };

                var moviesByCategories = movies.GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(x => new MovieCategory { Title = x.Key, Items = x.ToList() });

                Items = moviesByCategories.ToList();
            }
        }

        public class Movie
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Subtitle { get; set; }
            public string Image { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
        }

        public class MovieCategory
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public List<Movie> Items { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly assist

Comment: you have two `MoviesPageViewModel` one inside another one. it is not allowed in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class named `MoviesPageViewModel` declared as a class inside of `MoviesPageViewModel`, which is perhaps not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your nested class has the same name with a class which it is declared in. It is not possible:

```
  public class MoviesPageViewModel
    {
        public class MoviesPageViewModel
        {
```

Just remove the first one or change it to something like that:

```
  public class MoviesPageViewModel
    {
        public class OtherClassName
        {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MoviesPageViewModel
{
    public class MoviesPageViewModel
```

It's not a constructor, it's an inner type - and it's not allowed!

Try:

```
public class MoviesPageViewModel
{
    public MoviesPageViewModel(){
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you have two declarations of the MoviesPageViewModel class (typo?). Remove one:

```
namespace MVVM
{
    public class MoviesPageViewModel
    {
        public List<MovieCategory> Items { get; set; }

        public MoviesPageViewModel()
        {
```